# How can I load multiple ace editor sessions without multiple worker requests

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ace-editor

I have the following code which basically loads three JavaScript ace editor sessions:

But the problem is for each and every session it creates new **worker-javascript.js** network request for the **same mode**. I am supposed to have editor for 10 to 30 JavaScript ace-editor sessions in the single page to write different functions in JavaScript at various places, so this is eating memory and getting my Chrome browser crashed as it is requesting the worker every time for the same mode.

Following is my sample html file: (With angular app)

```html
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="editorApp">
<head>
  <title>Ace editor tst</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-ace/ui-ace.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ace-builds/src/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .e1 { height: 200px; margin-bottom: 5px;}
    .e2 { height: 200px; margin-bottom: 5px;}
    .e3 { height: 200px; margin-bottom: 5px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <div class="e1" ui-ace="{
  workerPath: 'bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/',
  useWrapMode : true,
  showGutter: true,
  theme:'twilight',
  firstLineNumber: 1,
  onLoad: aceLoaded,
  onChange: aceChanged,
  require: ['ace/ext/language_tools'],
  advanced: {
  enableSnippets: true,
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
  enableLiveAutocompletion: true
}
}"></div>
<div class="e2" ui-ace="{
workerPath: 'bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/',
useWrapMode : true,
showGutter: true,
theme:'twilight',
firstLineNumber: 1,
onLoad: aceLoaded,
onChange: aceChanged,
require: ['ace/ext/language_tools'],
advanced: {
enableSnippets: true,
enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
enableLiveAutocompletion: true
}
}"></div>
<div class="e3" ui-ace="{
workerPath: 'bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/',
useWrapMode : true,
showGutter: true,
theme:'twilight',
firstLineNumber: 1,
onLoad: aceLoaded,
onChange: aceChanged,
require: ['ace/ext/language_tools'],
advanced: {
enableSnippets: true,
enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
enableLiveAutocompletion: true
}
}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my controller: (index.js)

```js
var app = angular.module('editorApp', ['ui.ace']);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor){
        var _session = _editor.getSession();
        _session.setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
        var _renderer = _editor.renderer;
        _editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
    }

/*    $scope.acesession = "";
    $scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor){
        var _session = "";
        if(!$scope.acesession) {
            _session = _editor.getSession();
            _session.setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
            $scope.acesession = _session;
        }
        else {
            _session = $scope.acesession;
        }

        var _renderer = _editor.renderer;
        _editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
    }*/
});
```

I have even tried by using the same session (commented code above) as discussed at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/344 , but didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Plnkr is here http://plnkr.co/edit/lJUAW9EXsiC7RVuga9ia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Update the editor session to use the the worker only for the active ace editor.

```
_editor.on('focus', function () {
    _editor.getSession().setUseWorker(true);
});

_editor.on('blur', function () {
    _editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
});
var _session = _editor.getSession();
_session.setUseWorker(false);
_session.setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
var _renderer = _editor.renderer;
_editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
```

Working Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/B1fuFguofn8cwiUEFnyp?p=preview